# How to avoid from nested forms in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, forms

I have a view that show us following result:

[image: form]

as you can see every item has a delete button that need an item id and a form with delete method, on the other hand every item has a checkbox too, and I need form for all of them with a different method, look at this:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <div>
        @foreach($data as $channel)

            <div>

                <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $channel->id }}">

                <h4>{{ $channel->type }}</h4>
                <h4>{{ $channel->title }}</h4>

                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('channels.destroy', [$bot_name, $channel->id]) }}">
                    @csrf
                    @method('delete')
                    <x-button value="delete">
                        {{('Delete')}}
                    </x-button>
                </form>

            </div>

        @endforeach
    </div>
    <x-button value="next">
        {{('Next')}}
    </x-button>
</form>
```

How can I prevent this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Javascript (plain, framework or jquery) to mark your elements with some actions and creating different endpoints for each action.